# how to create a firewall rule in .net standard 2.0 which can Support in linux?

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core-6.0, .net-standard-2.0, windows-firewall

Currently we are using `NetFwTypeLib` COMReference for adding a firewall rule to out application ,but it working only on Windows

```
public static bool AddRule(Firewall Rule){
            INetFwRule firewallRule = (INetFwRule)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
            firewallRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW;
            firewallRule.Description = rule.RuleDescription;
            firewallRule.Direction = NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_.NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN;
            firewallRule.Enabled = true;
            firewallRule.ApplicationName = rule.ApplicationPath;
            firewallRule.RemoteAddresses = "LocalSubnet";
            firewallRule.InterfaceTypes = "All";
            firewallRule.Name = rule.RuleName;

            switch (rule.Protocol)
            {
                case FirewallRule.ProtocolType.TCP:
                    firewallRule.Protocol = (int)NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP; break;
                case FirewallRule.ProtocolType.UDP:
                    firewallRule.Protocol = (int)NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_UDP; break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rule", "The Protocol property of the firewall rule contains an invalid value!");
            }

            INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
            firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(firewallRule);
            return true;
```

}
this peace of code only Supported in Windows so How can I replace this peace of code into other library so our code will work on linux as well .

Comment: ok , Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos for the response , could you please suggest me some library that can work on linux OS .

Comment: There's no answer to this question. This code is working only with Windows Firewall, not just Windows. There are hundreds if not thousands of firewall products. What if the user runs ZoneAlarm for example? Or they use an enterprise firewall?

Comment: `suggest me some library` I don't think you understood what I wrote. For what product? ZoneAlarm? Or NGINX?

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos , Sorry for my Previous question Actually we are using a  ZoneAlarm for our local PC

Answer (score 0):

There is no library to cover all firewall products. As mentioned in the comments, most users on Windows use the built-in Windows Firewall. Some use other products like ZoneAlarm. The same is true for Linux: Ubuntu has `ufw`, other distros use `iptables`. And even then, nobody forces you to use `ufw` on Ubuntu, you could use an entirely different firewall if you wanted to. Each firewall product has a different API and you need to take care of them individually.

Comment: This sounds like a good opportunity for someone to create something that can have plug-in modules for each firewall.